# How can I count elements satisfying a condition in a group, with PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

with this query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', ts) ts, instrument
FROM test
GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', ts), instrument
ORDER BY ts
```

I am grouping rows by minutes but I would like to generate a boolean value that tells me if, in the group, there is at least one row with the timestamp where the seconds are < 10 and at least one row with the timestamp where the seconds are > 50.

In short, something like:

```
lessThan10 = false
moreThan50 = false
for each row in the one minute group:
    if row.ts.seconds < 10 then lessThan10 = true
    if row.ts.seconds > 50 then moreThan50 = true

return lessThan10 && moreThan50
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find out if all the records I aggregate cover the beginning and the end of the minute; it's ok if there are holes here and there, but it's possible the data we capture stops and restarts at second 40 for example and, in that case, I'd like to be able to discard the whole minute.
As the data rate varies quite a lot, I can't check for a minimum number of row. There may be a better solution to achieve this, so I'm open to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT()` to get the seconds of the `min` and `max` values of `ts`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', ts) ts, instrument,
       EXTRACT(SECOND FROM MIN(ts)) < 10 lessThan10, 
       EXTRACT(SECOND FROM MAX(ts)) > 50 moreThan50
FROM test
GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', ts), instrument
ORDER BY ts
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ed5aa29436a48b4682e908d7b56015c).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks. Being new to SQL, I keep thinking in general programming flow and it's not really helping me :D

Comment: is there an easy way to make a column that returns (lessThan10 && moreThan50)?

Comment: Add this column to the select list: `EXTRACT(SECOND FROM MIN(ts)) < 10 AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM MAX(ts)) > 50`